# Issue on deploying Kie-wb on WebShpere 8

Tags: java, jbpm, kie-wb

Tried to deploy KIE-WB distribution on WebSphere 8.0.0.4 following the [documentation](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/kie-wb-distributions/tree/master/kie-wb/kie-wb-distribution-wars/src/main/was8) , did try 6.1.0 and found that kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0-20141001.091451-145-was8.war is less error, however I am stuck at this error

```
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.service.SocialAdapterRepositoryAPI] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]for injection into 
 Field Injection Point, field :  org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.service.SocialAdapterRepositoryAPI org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialActivitiesEventObserver.socialAdapterRepository, Bean Owner : [1850105111,Name:null,WebBeans Type:MANAGED,API Types:[org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialActivitiesEventObserver,java.lang.Object],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
 InjectionType   :  [interface org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.service.SocialAdapterRepositoryAPI]
 Annotated       :  [Annotated Field,Base Type : interface org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.service.SocialAdapterRepositoryAPI,Type Closures : [interface org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.service.SocialAdapterRepositoryAPI, class java.lang.Object],Annotations : [@javax.inject.Inject()],Java Member Name : socialAdapterRepository]
 Qualifiers      :  [[@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]]
at org.apache.webbeans.util.InjectionExceptionUtils.throwUnsatisfiedResolutionException(InjectionExceptionUtils.java:92)
at org.apache.webbeans.container.ResolutionUtil.checkResolvedBeans(ResolutionUtil.java:96)
at org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectionResolver.getInjectionPointBean(InjectionResolver.java:256)
at org.apache.webbeans.inject.AbstractInjectable.inject(AbstractInjectable.java:100)
```

Since I have no experience with uberfire social API and there is not any document regards how to fix this issue, I am totally screwed. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on the SNAPSHOT builds, we're working on fixing it.
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1147929

Could you try the 6.1.0.Final instead?

Comment: Deploy the 6.1.0 final but had the error FileSystemPro E org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders <clinit> Can't initialize FileSystemProviders
                                 java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: KB005
 at java.util.ServiceLoader$ServiceIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:202)  not sure it is caused by firewall blocks Git or classpath issue.